Can we do background processing in php without using pthread?
Usecase:-I want to download a pdf but it take time approx 2 minute because the size of the pdf is big. so my current page is stucked until the download was completed so,I wanted to perform background processing in php.
I have perform Asynchronous processing but it won't work in my system.and i also used pcntl_fork and pthread but those or not supported in my php version
PHP Version:7.0.0

People often offload their background processing to scheduled scripts triggered by cron (for example). Depends on what exactly you're wanting to do though, you haven't discussed the use case

Please be clear, because currently it is unknow why this question/answer is not applicable to your situation: php execute a background process

I updated the usecase please refer to it.

Thanks. You could potentially use AJAX so it's a background request for the browser. But it's still a very long time to wait in web terms, so the user might get bored, or assume it's not working, or just forget and move on to another page (not realising that this might cancel their download). And also it will still use up webserver resources. If it really takes that long to produce the document, and you cannot optimise it, then consider another workflow - e.g. maybe ask the user for their email address, then hand the task off to a background cron job which generates the PDF and emails it.

Or are you saying that the PHP script is the one which is downloading a resource from another server? Your description is still ambiguous, I've just realised. Review [ask], remember we're not mind-readers, and consider showing us your current code as a [mre] of the issue, as well as providing a fully-detailed description of the situation so that it's 100% clear what you're trying to do.

Does it take 2 minutes to generate the PDF, or is the PDF big, or the connection slow, so it takes 2 minutes to transfer the PDF?

Just curious: Normal file streaming doesn't work for you?

I rolled back your last edit. Please don't change the question to something completely different - it makes a nonsense of all the previous comments and answers, and wastes the time of those people who wrote them. If you have a new and different problem, you need to post a new and different question. If you no longer wish to ask this question, you can delete it.

As you are ruling out the standard methods to do such a thing a roundabout way could be done by employing the approach detailed in this question:
PHP Fire and Forget POST Request
Instead of downloading the file in your php code and so blocking the site, send a HTTP request to another php script on your server and close the connection. This way you shouldn't have to wait till the download is finished, but you won't get any response when or if the download finished.

What if the calling script needs the downloaded data in order to continue what it's doing? We still don't know enough about the use case, IMO

That wouldn't work out with simple php site and pcntl_fork or pthread either though. You can either return a site (and keep the scenario responsive) or handle the download. But you are right I extrapolated from the little known info.
